# ActiveRecord scope of :uniqueness on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models:

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :lists, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :words, through: :lists
end
```

List.rb

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :words, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

Word.rb

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :list
    validates :title, uniqueness: {scope: :title}, presence: true
end
```

The uniqueness attribute in the Words model works by limiting only one unique word for all lists (e.g. List(1) and List(2) can not have any of the same words).

Is there a way to limit the scope of uniqueness to each list (e.g. List(1) can have the same words as List(2), but no single list can have the same word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Word`, try `validates_uniqueness_of :title, scope: :list_id`.

This should require the title to be unique within the subset of words belonging to the same list.

More info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of